# save PDF from html2canvas on server

Tags: php, html2canvas

I would like to ask about how I can save the generated PDF file (via htm2pdf) on a remote server?
I know how to save a file, but I do not know how to "pass" it to  to the BTOA function which will allow me to upload file; for example:

```
  var pdff = new html2pdf()
    .set({ html2canvas: { scale: 3 } })
    .from(element)
    .save(); //works, allows to download the correct file
    var pdf = btoa(pdff.output()); // I know, wrong syntax, how to write it correctly?
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "upload.php?nazwa=" + nazwa,
      data: {data: pdf},
    }).done(function(data){             
       console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Are you `HTML2PDF` in PHP or JS?

Comment: I'm using HTML2PDF in JS

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out! script below allows you to simultaneously download the file and simultaneously save it on the server :)

```
var pdff = new html2pdf()
    .set({ html2canvas: { scale: 3 } })
    .from(element)
    .save()
    .outputPdf().then(function(pdf) {
        var fi = btoa(pdf); 
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "upload.php?nazwa=file.pdf",
            data: {data: fi},
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }); 
    });
```